# Location of the saddle point

Tags: algorithm

I have the following problem

Assume  that we have a  9*8 matrix

A matrix is said to have a "saddle point", if in some position
is the smallest value in its row and the largest value in its column  .
In symbols , a[i][j]   is a saddle point if

```
 a[i][j]=min a[i][k]  ==max a[k][k]
             1<=k<=8      1<=k<=9
```

Please help me finding the computer location of the saddle point.

Comment: What have you achieved so far? Where do you have problems?

Comment: I disagree. Saddle points are, when a LOCAL minimum in one dimension happens to be a LOCAL maximum in the other dimension. It is not (only) the lowest value in a row & highest in a column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given *MxN* matrix, this is `O(MN)`, which is optimal.

```
INIT rowMin = [ +Infinify ] xM
INIT colMax = [ -Infinity ] xN

FOR r = 1..M
  FOR c = 1..N
    rowMin[r] = MIN(rowMin[r], mat[r][c])
    colMax[c] = MAX(colMax[c], mat[r][c])

FOR r = 1..M
  FOR c = 1..N
    IF mat[r][c] == rowMin[r] == colMax[c]
       DECLARE saddlePoint(r, c)
```

---

#### Why is this optimal?

Because there are *MxN* values, and they each need to be looked at, so for your answer to be certain (i.e. not probabilistic), the lowerbound is `O(MN)`.

#### Can this be optimized further?

You can optimize this a bit. It'll still be `O(MN)`, but instead of finding the maximum/minimum *values*, you find their *indices* instead. This can make the second phase `O(M)` in the best case (i.e. when there's a unique min/max in a row/column).

Note that in the worst case, there are `O(MN)` saddle points: that's when the numbers in the array are all equal.

Comment: I think you have a bug at line 2 of the code (-Infinity?); even though I don't get the ... x M nor ... x N notation

Comment: I'm pretty sure O(MN) is not optimal.

Comment: @unreason: yep, bug. Fixed. The notation is short for `[1,1,1] = [1]x3`

Comment: @Nick: there are `O(MN)` values. How can you answer this without looking at each one of them?

Comment: Sorry, you're right - I misread it as being greater than the number of values in the array, somehow. Still, your last loop is suboptimal - see my answer for an O(min(m, n)) solution for the last part. I see you've already alluded to the possibility, but it's really not hard to implement, either.

Comment: If you're using C/C++, you could use limits.h to populate rowMin and colMax with INT_MAX and INT_MIN respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Naive solution is to:

- find smallest values of all rows
- find largest values of columns
- see if any of them are at the same position

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell:

1. Iterate through each row, finding the column number of the smallest value in that row.
2. Iterate through each column, finding the row number of the largest value in that column.
3. Iterate through either rows-mins or column-maxes, checking if the corresponding cell is also the max in the other array.

Here's an implementation in Python:

```
def find_saddle_points(a):
  """Finds saddle points in a, a 2 dimensional array.

  Args:
    a: A 2 dimensional array in row-major (y, x) order.
  Returns:
    A list of (x, y) location of the saddle points.
  """
  # Holds a (value, column) tuple of the min value and its column for each row.
  row_mins = [min((a[row][col], col) for col in range(len(a[row]))) for row in range(len(a))]
  # Holds a (value, row) tuple of the max value and its row for each column.
  col_maxes = [max((a[row][col], row) for row in range(len(a))) for col in range(len(a[0]))]

  ret = []
  for row, (row_min, col) in enumerate(row_mins):
    if col_maxes[col][1] == row:
      ret.append((row, col))
  return ret
```

Comment: I don't understand python, but you said that your second phase is `O(min(M,N))`, and yet you claim to return all saddle points. In the worst case, every point is a saddle point, so the second phase would have to be `O(MN)`. How do you explain this? (+1, by the way)

Comment: You're quite right - it will return at most one saddle point per row (or column, if you reverse the final loop). This may or may not be a significant issue, depending on the application, since in the common case (an array without many repeated values), there can only be one saddle point.

Answer (score 0):

you answered the question yourself:

find the position of the minimum element in each row,
find the position of the maximum element in each column,

any position which occurs in both lists is a saddle point

there's room for improvement - but basically, that's it