# Python 3.x Finding saddle points in a matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, points, saddle

This is my **matrix**:

```
1  1  2  5  6  1     
5  6  8  5  6  7
10 12 10 12 11 11
8 10  5  6  8  9
6  5 10 12 15 19
```

and I would like to find it's [saddle points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point).

**COORDINATES** of **Saddle points** should be:

```
2 0 
2 2
0 4
```

So my question is. Can someone show me, how to make this in Python? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [question about saddle point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062161/question-about-saddle-point)

Comment: Check Nick Johnson's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3062708/2063361

Comment: Thank you i have found this topic. There is written that I should find smallest values of all rows, largest values of all columns and see if any of them are at the same position. But I don't know how to do the last and the most important step(check the position)..

Comment: For that you may use `my_list.index(num)`. It returns index of `num` value in `my_list` list.

Comment: Nick's answer if incomplete, as comments show. His function will return `[(2, 0)]` only.

Comment: Yeah it just return index of number in my list.(maybe my bad expression, sorry) But I want to find saddle points from my 2 new lists(list of the smallest values of all rows and list of the biggest values of all columns).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Python approach that assembles lists of the indices of all row/column mins and maxs and then uses set operations to find their intersections:

```
def allSaddles(matrix):
    rowmins = []
    rowmaxs = []
    colmins = []
    colmaxs = []

    for i,row in enumerate(matrix):
        m = min(row)
        M = max(row)
        for j,x in enumerate(row):
            if x == m: rowmins.append((i,j))
            if x == M: rowmaxs.append((i,j))

    t = [list(column) for column in zip(*matrix)] #transpose of matrix

    for j,col in enumerate(t): 
        m = min(col)
        M = max(col)
        for i,x in enumerate(col):
            if x == m: colmins.append((i,j))
            if x == M: colmaxs.append((i,j))

    return (set(rowmins) & set(colmaxs)) | (set(rowmaxs) & set(colmins))

M = [[1,1,2,5,6,1],    
[5,6,8,5,6,7],
[10,12,10,12,11,11],
[8,10,5,6,8,9],
[6,5,10,12,15,19]]

print(allSaddles(M))
```

Output: `{(0, 4), (2, 0), (2, 2)}`

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I have one more question. Is it able to print the coordinates on new lines? e.g 0,4 on first line, 2,0 on second line...

Comment: @JaroslavŠťastný The function returns the saddle points as a set. Once you have that, you can do what you want with it, including sorting it or using a for-loop to print it line by line.

Comment: Can I know why this step was performed to get the values " return (set(rowmins) & set(colmaxs)) | (set(rowmaxs) & set(colmins))" of the saddle point? Just curious as my knowledge on saddle point is weak

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different way to make it. Note that the input matrix is a `np.ndarray` :

```
def saddles(mat : np.ndarray) -> list:

    """
    returns the list of all saddle points of the input matrix

    """


    (N, M) = mat.shape

    jMax = np.argmax(mat, axis = 1) # index of col for max in each row
    iMin = np.argmin(mat, axis = 0) # index of row for min in each col

    IJMax = [(i,jMax[i]) for i in range(N)] # list of indexes of max of each row
    IJMin = [(iMin[j],j) for j in range(M)] # list of indexes of min of each col

    maxRowMinCol = list(set(IJMax) & set(IJMin)) # max of row, min of col


    iMax = np.argmax(mat, axis = 0) # index of row for max in each col
    jMin = np.argmin(mat, axis = 1) # index of col for min in each row

    IJMax = [(iMax[j],j) for j in range(M)] # list of indexes of max of each col
    IJMin = [(i,jMin[i]) for i in range(N)] # list of indexes of min of each row

    minRowMaxCol = list(set(IJMax) & set(IJMin)) # min of row, max of col


    return maxRowMinCol + minRowMaxCol
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my saddle point finder in python

```
import numpy as np


def is_saddle(row, column, *args):
    index = 0
    size = row * column
    matrix = np.arange(size).reshape(row, column)
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(column):
            matrix[i][j] = args[0][index]
            index = index + 1
    print(matrix)
    for item_row in matrix:
        column_number = 0
        min_item = np.amin(item_row)
        for i in range(len(item_row)):
            if min_item == item_row[i]:
                row_number = i
                reversed_matrix = matrix.transpose()
                max_item = np.amax(reversed_matrix[row_number])
                if max_item == min_item:
                    print("saddle point found : {}".format(min_item))

    return matrix


row = input("enter row")
column = input("enter column")
matrix = input("enter the matrix items")
is_saddle(row, column, matrix)
```

> **input sample: row = 2, column = 3, matrix = (1,2,3,4,5,6)**

Answer (score 0):

I have a different approach, looking for saddle points which are local, based on a few auxiliary 2d arrays:

```
def find_saddle(arr2d):

    xdiff = np.diff(arr2d, axis=0) # Derivative along 1st dim
    ydiff = np.diff(arr2d, axis=1) # Derivative along 2nd dim

# Saddle points are not in the "boundary" elements

    xdiff1 = xdiff[1:  , 1:-1]  # Shift matrix skipping 1st row
    xdiff2 = xdiff[ :-1, 1:-1]  # Cut the last row
    ydiff1 = ydiff[1:-1, 1:  ]  # Same, for columns
    ydiff2 = ydiff[1:-1,  :-1]

# A saddle points is a local maximum/minimum in one dimension (xdiff1*xdiff2 < 0) and in the other dimension (ydiff1*ydiff2 < 0), 
# but only in the combination max1&min2 or min1&max2 (xdiff1*ydiff1 < 0)
    ind = np.where((xdiff1*xdiff2 < 0) & (ydiff1*ydiff2 < 0) &
(xdiff1*ydiff1 < 0))
    saddle_points = []
    if len(ind) > 0:
        for j, x in enumerate(ind[0]):
            saddle_points.append([x + 1, ind[1][j] + 1])

    return saddle_points
```