# Searching for saddle elements in the n-dimensional matrix?

Tags: python, arrays

I wrote this code

```
 from math import *
import numpy as np
from random import *

n=int(input("Row size"))
m=int(input("Column size"))

def MakeMatr(n):
    matr = np.random.randint(-10,10,size=(n,m))
    return matr

matr=MakeMatr(n)
print(matr)

a=0

for row in range(n):
    if 0 in matr[row]:
         for col in range(m):
            if matr[row][col]<0:
                a+=1
print(" Number of negative elements in rows where there is at least one zero ", a)
```

and now i need to search saddle points.. but how i don't know, can u help me? 
I know what it means but don't know how write it in Python

Comment: What is your expected output? How the saddle points should look like?

Comment: @powerPixie it looks like: it must be min in row and max in column

Comment: It doesn't clarify much. Look at this example, the person provided the matrix and the output. I don't understand cyrilic and have no idea of your input matrix either. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920505/python-3-x-finding-saddle-points-in-a-matrix